# Copy extremely large buffer data from watch to a text file

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2015

So i have this very very large buffer of size 1296000 which i want to copy at the time of debug from my VS 2015 watch to a text file. The file stream or cout commands are not working thus left to do this manually.

interested to know if there is any quick way to copy all the buffer values i.e. [0] ...to...[1296000]... As of now when i try to do this my systems hangs and copying data in say multiple of 3000's or so is very time consuming.

i need to do this as this buffer / txt file will be used as input to my another code. Please suggest some quick way to use the watch windo in VS.

Answer (score 0):

If press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> is also not convenient for you in debug watch window, the workaround I know that using the immediate window (Debug -> Windows -> Immediate), you can use the "?" to view the value of a variable and then copy it to text file.

IInspectable Shared another workaround using the data breakpoint and output the value:

[Visual Studio. Debug. How to save to a file all the values a variable has had during the duration of a run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39789974/visual-studio-debug-how-to-save-to-a-file-all-the-values-a-variable-has-had-du)

Comment: Using immediate is helpful but it only displays first 100 values and then i have to switch to Watch again for rest of the values. if you have a workaround with that it would be helpful.

Comment: I‘m think of using the debugging extension, but it is not easy. I modify my reply, other community members shared a workaround using the data breakpoint and show the value to the output window, maybe it is a better workaround than my previous one.