# Visual Studio. Debug. How to save to a file all the values a variable has had during the duration of a run?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, variables

I am watching a variable that gets assigned thousands of values during a single run. It is being set several times and is hard to keep track of the code workflow just by setting breakpoints where it is being reassigned. 
Is there a way to output all the values the variable had to a .txt file? I want to achive this without modifying the actual C++ code, just using the debugging tools.

Comment: Use can use trace() command to output the variable status to the debugger console. If you want to dump the values to a text file you can do it use fstream  functions.

Comment: Most simplistic way: Set up a trace point that dumps the value (with some signature of your liking). When done you can simply copy the Debug output to a file, and search for your signature. In contrast to @seccpur's suggestion, this doesn't require any code changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get really close to what you're looking for, you need to combine two features of Visual Studio: Data breakpoints and trace points. Data breakpoints allow you to notify the debugger, whenever the store value in memory changes. To set a data breakpoint, launch the debugger, and select *Debug* → *New Breakpoint* → *Data Breakpoint...*:

[image: New Data Breakpoint]

Since we are interested in the variable `myValue`, we're setting the address to `&myValue`, and set the size to 4 bytes (since that's what an `int` is on Windows):

[image: Data Breakpoint Settings]

Now that would be pretty cool as-is already. But for non-intrusive logging, we'll set the *Actions* as well:

[image: Data Breakpoint Actions]

The important settings are the log message (`[MYSIG]` is an arbitrary signature, so that the interesting log entries can later be filtered), that dumps the value of the variable, as well as the *Continue execution* check box. The latter makes this non-intrusive (or low-intrusive; logging lots of information does have a noticeable impact on runtime performance).

With that in place, running this code

```
inline void DataTracepoint() {
    volatile int myValue{ 0 };
    for ( int i = 0; i < 10; ++i ) {
        myValue = i;
    }
}
```

produces the following output in the *Debug* output pane:

> ```
> [MYSIG] myValue = 0
> [MYSIG] myValue = 1
> [MYSIG] myValue = 2
> [MYSIG] myValue = 3
> [MYSIG] myValue = 4
> [MYSIG] myValue = 5
> [MYSIG] myValue = 6
> [MYSIG] myValue = 7
> [MYSIG] myValue = 8
> [MYSIG] myValue = 9
> ```

This output can then be easily analyzed in your favorite text processor.